# ArrayIndexOufofBoundExceptin in zipping file by android programming

Tags: java, android

I am newbie in android programming, Currently i am trying to do zipping multiple files in android.  in my SD card  a zipfile is created  but it has no files inside and 0.00 byte showing . In logcat  i have got some exception like

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2040; regionStart=0; regionLength=-1

at java.util.Arrays.checkOffsetAndCount(Arrays.java:1732)

Here is my code

```
package com.example.zipfile;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

import android.util.Log;


public class CompressFile 
{

    public static final int Buffer=2040;
    public String[]localfiles;
    public String zippedFile;

    public CompressFile(String[]localfileset,String zipFileset) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        this.localfiles=localfileset;
        this.zippedFile= zipFileset;

    }

    public  void zip()
    {

        try
        {
            BufferedInputStream bufferstream=null;
            FileOutputStream fileout=new FileOutputStream(zippedFile);
            ZipOutputStream zipout=new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(fileout));

            byte[]data=new byte[Buffer];

            for(int i=0;i<localfiles.length;i++)
            {
                Log.d("add",localfiles[i]);
                Log.v("Compress","AddingFiles:"+ localfiles[i]);
                FileInputStream fileinput=new FileInputStream(localfiles[i]);
                bufferstream=new BufferedInputStream(fileinput,Buffer);
                ZipEntry zipentry=new ZipEntry(localfiles[i].substring(localfiles[i].lastIndexOf("/")+1));
                zipout.putNextEntry(zipentry);



                int count;

                while((count=bufferstream.read(data,0,Buffer))!=-1);
                {
                    zipout.write(data,0,count);
                }

                bufferstream.close();




            }

            zipout.close();


        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }



}
```

and my MainActvity code

```
package com.example.zipfile;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        String[]filelist=new String[2];
        String path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
        filelist[0]=path+"/facebooklogo1.png";
        filelist[1]=path+"/formpicture.jpg";

        CompressFile compress=new CompressFile(filelist,path+"/Testzip.zip");
        compress.zip();




    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
    {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

i am not getting why it is happening , A help is appreciated 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

1) Check file path
2) **localfiles[i].substring(localfiles[i].lastIndexOf("/")+1)** this should be unique entry for Zip file.

`

```
byte[] data = new byte[4096];
  // Read bytes from packed file and store them in the ZIP output stream
  int bytesNum;
  while ((bytesNum = bufferstream.read(data)) > 0) {
        zipout.write(data, 0, bytesNum);
  }
```

`

Comment: Thanks for your comment but  i have changed this but still getting same problem  i have wrote  file path by hardcode now like  
"/sdcard/facebooklogo1.png", 
"/sdcard/formpicture.jpg"
"filelist, /sdcard/Testzip.zip "
But same  problem is happening. same exception is occurring

Answer (score 0):

i have re modified  my code i didn't  buffredInputStream  this time thanks rahul  for your suggestion . Here is my code  its working

```
package com.example.ziptest;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


    String path= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();// stating relative path of SD card rather than hard coded path
    String zipfile=path+File.separator+"Filekb.zip"; // the new  compressed file with its path
    String storagefile1=path+File.separator+"facebooklogo1.png"; // local file which is going to be compressed
    String storagefile2=path+File.separator+"formpicture.jpg"; //   second local file which is going to be compressed
    String[]storagefiles= {storagefile1,storagefile2};// put this local files in a array
    public byte[]buffer=new byte[2040]; // create buffer
    FileInputStream fileinput;
    FileOutputStream fileoutput;
    ZipOutputStream zipout;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        zip();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void zip()
    {

        try
        {
            fileoutput=new FileOutputStream(zipfile);
            zipout =new ZipOutputStream(fileoutput);
            for(int i=0;i<storagefiles.length;i++)
            {
             File   storagefileindex=new File(storagefiles[i]);
             Log.d("Add", storagefiles[i]);
             Log.v("compressing","Adding"+storagefiles[i]);

             fileinput=new FileInputStream(storagefileindex);

             zipout.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(storagefileindex.getName()));

             int bytecount;

             while((bytecount= fileinput.read(buffer))>0)
             {
                 zipout.write(buffer,0,bytecount);
             }

             zipout.closeEntry();
             fileinput.close();


            }
            zipout.close();
        }

        catch(Exception ioe)
        {
            Log.d(zipfile, "Error occurs in Creating zip");
        }

    }




}
```